# Transform a definite integral sum into only one integral (double integrals)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$I= \int_{0}^{8}\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{1+\sqrt{y+1}}\frac{4ye^x}{x^2}dxdy + \int_{-1}^{0}\int_{1-\sqrt{y+1}}^{1+\sqrt{y+1}}\frac{4ye^x}{x^2}dxdy$$

From the plot of the integration region I know that it is a parabola enclosed by a linear function, however I only know how to express it as a sum of integrals but I only need one integral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at a plot of the integration region, it looks like it might be more convenient to switch the order of integration.  We see that $0<x<4$ in the region, and for a fixed value of $x$, we have $x(x-2) < y < 2x$, so the region is $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid0<x<4,\ x(x-2) < y < 2x\}$ and the integral is
$$I = \int_0^4 \int_{x(x-2)}^{2x} \frac{4ye^x}{x^2}\ dy\ dx$$